# How to remove versions with sed

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, sed

The following python metadata file contains the following required libraries:

```
Requires-Python: >=3
Requires-Dist: hello (~=0.1.1)
Requires-Dist: bar (~=1.14)
Requires-Dist: hello-world (~=1.10)
Requires-Dist: test (~=1.1) ; python_version < "3.4"
Requires-Dist: test-bar
...
```

How to use a single `sed` bash command to search and replace all versions from all required libraries?

**Here is the expected output:**

```
Requires-Python: >=3
Requires-Dist: hello
Requires-Dist: bar
Requires-Dist: hello-world
Requires-Dist: test
Requires-Dist: test-bar
...
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GNU` `sed`:

```
sed 's/(.*//' file
```

Output:

```
Requires-Python: >=3
Requires-Dist: hello
Requires-Dist: bar
Requires-Dist: hello-world
Requires-Dist: test
Requires-Dist: test-bar
```

**Explanation:**

```
(.*    : to match the pattern starting from '(' to the end of the line
//      : to empty or to remove the matched pattern
```